# Changing foreground color of Recycler view when an item is selected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

How to change foreground color of Recycler view when an item is selected ?

e.g All other items except the selected item needs to be with different foreground color.[image: Google allo assistant]

Comment: You can add onTouchItemListener on item and change the background color of the drawable programatically.

Comment: I need to change foreground color of the recycler view but it will create a foreground layer over the selected item as well. Any solution with the selected item's foreground color remains unaffected ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with drawable selector.
Put `bg.xml` in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Now set this instead of your background.

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    ...
    />
```

You just need to set selected in your adapter.

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: will this make recyclerview expect for selected item like shown in question? I don't think so.

Comment: @RahulKumar Okay, I took it wrong. I will post right solution.